# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 2021

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat8

I have a production server that uses Tomcat and MySQL. Today all websites, stopped connecting to it's respective database.

When restarting Tomcat, shows that the connection pool cannot be created for all websites/databases. Here's the error log (for one website):

```
23-Apr-2021 12:18:49.438 INFO [evaluaciones-grupocomidas.com-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/evaluaciones-grupocomidas.com/ROOT.xml]
23-Apr-2021 12:18:49.690 SEVERE [evaluaciones-grupocomidas.com-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
        com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:736)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:668)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
                at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
                at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
                at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:332)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:557)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:253)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

And the content of ROOT.xml is:

```
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/rhwebDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="false"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            validationInterval="30000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            maxActive="5"
            minIdle="0"
            maxIdle="5"
            maxWait="10000"
            initialSize="2"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            logAbandoned="true"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
            username="grupocom_rhuser"
            password="mypwd"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/grupocom_rhweb?serverTimezone=EST5EDT"/>
```

This problem started today and I'm running out of options. It was working fine for months (or years) maybe.

The JDBC driver is: mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar (an it's located under %CATALINA_HOME%/lib/
MySQL version is: 5.7.34

I've already tried removing the "serverTimezone" from the url parameter, using server's IP instead of 127.0.0.1 and other things but it's still not working.

Any help will be really appreciated

UPDATE

I've found on another log file the rest of the excepction, which might be relevant:

```
        Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
            at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
            at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)
            at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:428)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:316)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:352)
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding request parameter `enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2` to the connection URL did the trick for me. (e.g. jdbc:mysql://mydb:3306/myschema?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2)

Check out https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103828

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this, doing what other post here suggested:

I commented/disabled these lines on the java.security file:

```
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
#DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
#include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

In my case, java.security file is located in:

./usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/security/

Comment: The better solution would be to upgrade your MySQL installation so it can use a more recent and secure version of TLS.

Comment: Agree, however it's not that old 5.7.34. My server was down for about 4 hours which might or might not cost me some clients. These automatic updates should be done on Sundays only, instead of random unkown days.

Comment: This is a dirty bandage on a gaping festering bleeding wound. It stops the bleeding, but does not fix the problem. 

TLSv1.1 needs to be disabled for security reasons, but for some reason the mysql DB which does accept TLSv1.2 socket connections, is unable to negotiate the initial handshake without getting this error. For some reason the tomcat jdbc is handshaking with TLSv1.1 even with a  "?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2" in the connection URL.